# react-router always shows main page

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Im trying to implement react-router into a react SPA to add some urls but the main App just shows on every route that is set up.

Heres the Main app code

```
render: function () {
        return (

            <div className="row panel panel-default">

                <h2 className="text-center">Projects</h2>

                <ul>
                    <li><Link to="/1">About</Link></li>
                    <li><Link to="/2">Inbox</Link></li>
                </ul>

                {

                    <div className="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">

                        <Header itemsStore={this.firebaseRefs.items}/>
                        <hr />
                        <div className={"content " + (this.state.loaded ? 'loaded' : '')}>
                            <List items={this.state.items}/>
                            {this.deleteButton()}
                        </div>
                    </div>

                }

                {this.props.children}

            </div>
        )

    },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `<App>` component needs to render `this.props.children`

```
var App = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div id="nav_bar">links links links layout whatever</div>
                <div id="content">
                    {/* Route component gets rendered here */}
                    {this.props.children}
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

React-router examples: https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/tree/master/examples

Comment: How exactly do i do that? Im new to React.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have to browse with the Nav links or should it work if it type in the address bar direct?

Comment: I think it should work if you just play with the URL, give it a try. I think it'll work